# GRUB 2.02 - no output in command line mode

Tags: grub2, grub, console, output

When I am entering GRUB bash-like console mode and entering commands `ls` `ls -lh` to show available partitions there is no output.
Following similar question @ Unix&Linux Stack, I already turned off the Secure Boot using shim-sgined reboot (MOK managment) - while booting there is a notification that boot is insecure but it didn't fix the problem.

Any suggestions?

PS: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (x64) on Acer Switch 11

Answer (score 0):

I suffer from the very same issue.
I also use secure boot, but I don´t think this is related to secure boot. Secure boot does not block device access, it only verifies bootloaders.

Have you found a fix yet?